# Dynamically replace ad tags

Tags: javascript, ads

Once and for all I'd like to settle this issue I am dealing with since years. It's quite simple: I have a site, and I have some ads on it. The ads are JavaScript tags from various partners. They are alwaysd hosted on external servers, vary greatly and render all kinds of things: iframes, flash layers, whatever, in various sizes and shapes and so on.

With the site behaving more and more like an application, I'd like to be able to load new ads via JavaScript (and not with a page reload). Simply said, I'd like to document-write a new ad tag on the site. Problem is - and has always been, that the whole web page will then be replaced with the new JS code.

What solutions (other than iframes!) are out there?

Comment: Did you try to append the ad element rather then document.write - ing it? what exactly do you want to replace?

Comment: put a wrapper arround your ads and reload its content with ajax

Comment: None of these solutions work. Let me clarify: 

I have a container like this:

`<div id="ad">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://my.adpartner.net/ads/ad.js"></script>
</div>`

The script can do just about anything, usually it will load other scripts, deeply nested iframes, document-write other scripts, and so on. If I the container's content is replaced (e.g. with jquery/ajax), the whole page can become blank, because you cannot document-write stuff after the page has been rendered. Appeding the code does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of divs for your ad containers, use iframes. You can inject scripts into these frames without upsetting your outer document (since the iframe will have a different `document` object).

Comment: Yeah, but my question was "... (other than iframes) ... ?"

Comment: Ah. Is there a particular reason you are looking for a different solution?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Most of all: iframes don't allow the ads to resize dynamically and "escape the iframe". Of course, this would generally be possible, but not when you don't know what the ad will do and when you don't have any influence on the said third-party code, which is most often the case with ad tags.

Hence my initial question to a year-old problem I was hoping a solution for: Is it possible to insert and execute a JavaScript that itself uses document.write (or any other code) into a document **after** the page has loaded?

Comment: Calling `document.write` when the page is already loaded will implicitly call `document.open` which clears your page. Iframes prevent this by substituting a new sandboxed document that any scripts inside it interact with. If you want to add ads that you have no control over after the page is loaded and that don't wrap themselves in an iframe before calling document.write, you will need to place them in an iframe yourself.

Comment: It seems like what you should be asking is how to allow an iframe to style itself. You could query  style information, etc. from the iframe's document and adjust the dimensions of the iframe in your page accordingly. Something of a pain and somewhat brittle, but you can't cede control of your document to a `document.write`ing script, and this is a way to allow a form of 'escape' to the iframe without it having free reign.